# Indentation problems with Vim

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

I have a few problems when editing files with vim that have been created with other editors (Sublime Text in this case). Vim and Sublime Text seems to have the same settings for the indentation. look what I get when editing with Vim :

[image]

And with Sublime Text :

[image]

Here is my .vimrc :

```
set autoindent
set expandtab
set smarttab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: IMO, this is not indentation problem. you should tell what are the characters before the `=` tab? spaces? mixed? how many are they?

Comment: They are tabs. One tab is 2 characters (both in my vim and sublime text config).

Comment: does this help? `set ts=2`

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you Kent.

Answer (score 2):

This is not indentation problem, instead, it is a `<tab>` display problem.
you could try to set `tabstop` option to achieve your goal.

`:h 'ts'` to gain more info.